# LinkedIn Internal Server Error

Tags: internal-server-error, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn API to share my contents on the company page. Since last 3-4 days, I am getting an error.

> "LinkedIn::Errors::InformLinkedInError: LinkedIn had an internal
>   error. Please let them know in the forum. (500): Internal Server
>   Error"

I have not done any code change that shall break my application.

How do I report this error to LinkedIn? What details are required to be shared?

Comment: _I have not done any code change that shall break my application..._ It is not breaking _your_ application... it is an internal server error

Comment: I've also faced the same issue. LinkedIn::Errors::InformLinkedInError: LinkedIn had an internal error. Please let them know in the forum. (500): Internal Server Error

Do you know how to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd prepare the shortest code that triggers the problem: just the bare minimum that is needed to replicate it. Send it to them just as if it was a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here on StackOverflow.

Imagine you are the LinkedIn developer solving this problem: how would you like to receive this error report? Ideally if it was some short piece of code that you could run locally and observe what exactly is being sent to the API. (Of course the code has to actually trigger the problem!)

Comment: The token, secret and company page id need to replaced with actual values. I am able to see results up to fetching profile information. But content sharing on the company page is failing. Below is the error. LinkedIn::Errors::InformLinkedInError: LinkedIn had an internal error. Please let them know in the forum. (500): Internal Server Error

Comment: Please see above ^^^

Comment: class LinkedInConnect < ActiveRecord::Base
 #this method creates a new linked in client and gives him all the permissions.
 def self.create_linked_client
     # get your api keys at https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer
  client = LinkedIn::Client.new(ENV['LINKEDIN_APP_ID'], ENV['LINKEDIN_APP_SECRET'])
  client.authorize_from_access("81--021f5574-3f60-4c63-9d35-558cc1fe0399", "eb91584d-9ab8-43d8-82cd-eaa4e00ce505")
  client.profile
  client.add_company_share(Identity.last.uid, {"visibility": { "code": "anyone" },"comment": "Testing a full company share!")
   end
end
`

Comment: The project is in ruby. We have used the https://github.com/hexgnu/linkedin (linkedin (1.1.0)) gem. `

Comment: `class LinkedInConnect < ActiveRecord::Base                                       
def self.create_linked_client                                                                       client = LinkedIn::Client.new(ENV['LINKEDIN_APP_ID'], ENV['LINKEDIN_APP_SECRET']) client.authorize_from_access("81--021f5574-3f60-4c63-9d35-558cc1fe0399", "eb91584d-9ab8-43d8-82cd-eaa4e00ce505") client.profile client.add_company_share(Identity.last.uid, {"visibility": { "code": "anyone" },"comment": "Testing a full company share!") end end `

Comment: @KedarKulkarni the comments you've added here belong to the body of your question, please move the text & code there.